# Is there anyway to gracefully handle App Engine session serialization errors?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a Java App Engine app and whenever we modify any classes that are serialized as part of the session anyone that had a pre-existing session is broken (since the object persisted or in memcache is no longer compatible with the new object). I've done a bunch of searching and it seems as though there's no way to get those users working again unless they clear their cookies or we clear every entry in _ah_SESSION. The error happens so high up that the browser is sent a blank page, so we can't even do something like returning a page that can delete the cookies with javascript. I've tried creating a servlet filter, but the error happens before any filters are processed.

This appears to be a pretty wide-spread problem - I can't believe there's no way to handle this.

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: I'm curious to see if anyone can answer this.  Other than blowing away every _ah_SESSION entity in the datastore, I'm not sure how else to handle it.

Comment: All they have to do is catch the error and create a new session from scratch. What are the problems with that approach? Maybe an option to turn on that behavior. Making matters worse is that every task invocation creates a new entry in _ah_SESSION. We've got some 30k entries that need deleting and that's with a cron job that runs _ah/sessioncleanup every 2 minutes (only about 2000 of these are expired sessions, so running that more often won't help anyway).